# Fugenkonsonanten bei zusammengesetzten Wörtern

Tags: compound, linking-elements

Es ist für Ausländer besonders schwierig, Fugenkonsonanten korrekt einzusetzen. Es gibt zwar einige regionale Unterschiede im deutschen Sprachraum (Adventkranz versus Adventskranz), aber ansonsten haben Muttersprachler keinerlei Schwierigkeiten damit.

Gibt es dazu generelle Regeln?
Gibt es Studien, ob Muttersprachler erfundene Wörter überwiegend in derselben Weise zusammensetzen?
(Also z. B.: Ich gehe auf den Markt und kaufe Frecke. Mit dem größeren Freck möchte ich einen Kuchen backen. Wie heißt der Kuchen?)

Comment: Freckenkuchen - *en* nach einigen Nomen, die den Genitiv mit [e]s und Plural mit e bilden --- Frecke ist hier Plural, so wie "kaufe Möhren, Äpfel und Frecke". Und ich mag den Geschmack des Apfels aber nicht den des Freck[e]s.

Comment: Übrigens finde ich *Frecke* als Plural merkwürdig. Eine Zecke, viele Zecken; eine Hecke, viele Hecken; eine Decke, viele Decken.

Comment: Falls meine Comments Upvotes bekommen, beantwortet das deine Frage, ob Muttersprachler erfunde/neue/unbekannte Wörter in derselben Weise behandeln?! ;)

Comment: @Em1 Der Singular ist aber nicht Frecke sondern Freck: ein Bock, zwei Böcke; ein Reck, zwei Recke. - Auch, wenn ich keinen Kuchen mit Böcken machen würde, wäre es bei mir übrigens analog zu "Böckekuchen" "Freckekuchen".

Comment: @AlexanderKosubek Ja, richtig. Ich hab den ersten Kommentar auf "der Freck" aufgebaut, daher auch "des Freck(e)s"; sonst wäre es "der Frecke" (basierend auf die Frecke). Aber *Reck* ist ein gutes Beispiel; ich hab verzweifelt ein passendes Wort gesucht. - Aber *Recke* als Plural klingt für mich auch ungewohnt, man sagt sowas einfach zu selten. --- und für mich wäre es *Bockkuchen* äquivalent zu *Apfelkuchen*; daher ist auch *Freckkuchen* wahrscheinlich möglich.

Comment: Ich schlage "Freckskuchen" vor, analog zu "Dreck – Dreckskuchen" (wobei ich ebenfalls betonen will, dass ich keinen Kuchen aus Dreck backen würde :-)).

Comment: Was den Plural von Freck angeht, klingt Frecks übrigens auch nicht schlecht. Analog zu "Deck" – "Decks", "Reck" – "Recks" (*nicht* "Recke", ein Recke ist was anderes), "Leck" – "Lecks", "Dock" – "Docks". Aber für den Plural mit "-e" gibt es auch Vergleichsbeispiele mit "-eck": "Gedeck" – "Gedecke", "Besteck" – "Bestecke", "Gesteck" – "Gestecke". Wobei mir jetzt auffällt, dass das alles zweisilbige Wörter sind. Und "-en" als Plural gibt es auch: "Fleck" – "Flecken".

Comment: @celtschk Dann korrigier mal [wiktionary](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reck)

Comment: Ähnliches, aber existierendes Wort: "Frack" (langer Herrenrock). Wie heißt ein Schneider, der hauptsächlich Fracks herstellt? Er heißt "Frackschneider" oder "Frackmacher". Es gibt auch das Wort "Fracksausen", dass "Angst" bedeutet und sich von der beschleunigten Darmaktivität ängstlicher Menschen ableitet. In allen Fällen gibt es keinen Fugen-Buchstaben.

Comment: :) Auf jeden Fall ist ein Teil der Frage schon mal beantwortet. Jeder hat eine andere Idee bzw. Vorstellung, wie das Wort gebildet werden muss.

Comment: @Em1: Wiktionary ist hier widersprüchlich, denn der Plural "Recke" wird angeblich "Recks" ausgesprochen (siehe unter Aussprache). Der Plural scheint in jedem Fall extrem selten zu sein, ich würde aber auch "Recks" bevorzugen.

Comment: @Philipp Duden sagt übrigens, beides ist richtig.

Answer (score 6):

Zu dieser eher alten Frage passt der [AdA](http://www.atlas-alltagssprache.de/runde-3/f01a-d/) ganz gut:
- [image: Rinderbraten]

[image: Rindfleisch]

[image: Schweinebraten]

Answer (score 5):

"Fugenkonsonanten" ist nicht ausreichend. Korrekterweise muss es "Fugenlaut" oder "Fugenlaute" heißen, da auch z. B. ein "e" ("Hund" + "Leine" = "Hundeleine") verwendet werden kann.

Zusammengesetzte Wörter (Komposita) sind eine der Stärken der deutschen Sprache ("Donaudampfschifffahrtsgesellschaftskapitänsmütze"). Damit ein zusammengesetztes Wort aussprechbar ist, werden bei Bedarf unterschiedliche Fugenelemente eingefügt. Welche genau bleibt oftmals dem Sprachgefühl überlassen, eine feste Regel für alle Fälle gibt es nicht. Das laute Aussprechen hilft einem meistens: "Hundleine" und "Kapitänmütze" klingen nicht, "Hundeleine" und "Kapitänsmütze" hingegen schon und sind flüssig zu sprechen.

Manchmal werden auch Fugenelemente eingefügt, um eine Verwechslung mit einem anderen Wort zu verhindern. Beispiel: "Land" + "Mann" = "Landsmann", weil es das Wort "Landmann" (Mann vom Lande) schon gibt. Das Wort "Landsmann" bezeichnet einen Menschen aus dem gleichen Land, also ein Deutscher, ein Bayer, ...

Noch eine Bemerkung zum "Schweinsbraten": Als Bayer ist für mich die Kombination aus "Schwein" und "Braten" nicht ohne ein Fugenelement vernünftig aussprechbar. In Bayern ist das der "Schweinsbraten" (das ist ein fester bayrischer Begriff), analog der "Schweinshaxen")

Ich finde, dass dies in dem Wikipedia-Artikel [Fugenlaut](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fugenlaut) besonders gut dargelegt wird.

Comment: Beachte auch: Die Hund-e-leine aber der Hund-s-stern. Das Kind-er-mädchen aber die Kind-s-mutter.

Answer (score 3):

Meines Wissens gibt es keine generelle Regel dafür. Diese Fugenkonsonanten sind doch sogar ein beliebtes Instrument, um bei der Bundeswehr Rekruten zu verwirren. ("Es heißt Dreiecktuch und nicht Dreieckstuch. Es ist ja auch die Telefonzelle und nicht die Telefonszelle." Stimm so übrigens nicht wirklich.)

Wobei mir da gerade eine eventuelle Regelmäßigkeit auffällt: Könnte es vielleicht von dem Zweck der Zusammensetzung abhängen?

```
Telefonzelle - Eine Zelle für das Telefon
Kinderteller - Ein Teller für Kinder

Ortsnetzbereich - Der Netzbereich des Orts
Monatslohn - Der Lohn des Monats
```

Andererseits ... Mondschein und Freundeskreis sind dann wieder Gegenbeispiele ...

Ich bleibe also bei meiner anfänglichen Aussage: Es gibt hier keine Regel.

Comment: Es gibt bestimmte eine Regel, oder zumindest eines Faustregel. [Fugenelemente - canoo.net](http://www.canoo.net/services/WordformationRules/Komposition/WB-Elements/Fuge.html)

Comment: Ich gehe davon aus, dass die Regel, wenn nicht ausschließlich dann doch hauptsächlich, mit der schwierigeren Artikulation bim Fehlen von Fugenelementen zu tun hat. Wo diese nicht gegeben ist, fehlt das Fugenelement. - Daher Dreieck-s-tuch aber Telefon-zelle - weil -kt- schwieriger auszusprechen ist als -nz-.

Comment: Wobei "Schweinbraten" eigentlich nicht so schwer auszusprechen wäre (jedenfalls nicht schwerer als etwa "Weinbrand"), trotzdem wird daraus der Schweinebraten (obwohl zumindest in Vor-Klebefleisch-Zeiten wohl nie Fleisch von mehr als einem Schwein im Braten steckte – gespickte Braten mal ausgenommen) oder in Süddeutschland der Schweinsbraten.

Comment: Oder Schweinsbraten; beides richtig :)

Comment: @celtschk: Die Beobachtung, dass der Schwein**e**braten typischerweise aus nur einem Schwein gemacht wird, ist übrigens ein schöner Beleg dafür, dass die Fugenelemente eben *nicht* Plural- bzw. Genitiv-Bildungen sind.

Comment: Sonst müsste man aus dem Orangensaft Äpfelsaft folgern. ;) Allerdings sehe ich aus dem einen Schwein nur die Ablehnung des Plurals sich ergeben - wie folgt daraus, dass es kein Genitiv ist?

Comment: Man beachte auch die Verschiedenheit der Fugen: Hundeleine und Hundekuchen, aber Hundstage und hundsgemein (wohingegen *Hundnase nur bei Loriot nachgewiesen ist).

Comment: Was ist mit der Hundkatzemaus aus den Montagsmalern? <flitz>

Comment: Apropos Montagsmaler: Manchmal ist die korrekte Wahl des Fugenlautes wichtig (zumindest beim Schreiben): Montagsarbeiten können nur schlecht am Dienstag durchgeführt werden, Montagearbeiten hingegen schon. :-)

Comment: Neben dem Mondschein gibt es auch den Mondenschein.