# Word composition in German

Tags: word-usage, compound, linking-elements

When we have a German word composed of two or more terms, is there always an 's' between the two words? Someone who lived in Germany for a long time told me that there is always an 's', but as far as I remember there are words that don't need 's' in between. However, as my level is not that good in German, I can't think of any examples.

Comment: [Fugenkonsonanten bei zusammengesetzten Wörtern](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/5253/1224)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The s is called "Fugen-s" and is not always used. There is no general rule for its use, so its appliance is a question of feeling.

It is generally used when the first word ends with -tum, -ling, -ion, -tät, -heit, -keit, -schaft, -sicht, -ung as well as with Verbs used as Noun ending with -en:

> Altertumsforschung, Frühlingserwachen, Kommunionsfest, Realitätsverlust, Einheitsfeier, Heiterkeitsanfall, Eigenschaftswort, Ansichtskarte, Erinnerungsvermögen
>
> Essensreste, Lebensfreude, Leidensweg, Redensart, Schlafenszeit, Sehenswürdigkeit, Sterbenswörtchen, Wissenslücke
>
> Schadensersatz, but: Schadenfreude

(and a lot more, not necessarily following the rule above)

There is no *Fugen-s* in

> Weltkugel, Nachtzug, Fruchtsaft, Kammerdiener, Lageplan, Redezeit, Musikzimmer, Naturschutz, Schurwolle, Räuberhauptmann, Ritterburg, Steuererklärung, Zigeunerjunge, Nebelhorn, Paddelboot, Pendeluhr, Wendeltreppe, Nebenstraße, Ladenpassage, Rasenfläche, Wagenachse, Grußkarte, Lastwagen, Sitzkissen, Putzmittel, Herzkammer (and many more)

(from [zwiebelfisch](http://www.spiegel.de/kultur/zwiebelfisch/zwiebelfisch-der-gebrauch-des-fugen-s-im-ueberblick-a-293195.html))

Note that the use of *Fugen-s*'s differs in different German speaking Countries.

See [Wikipedia: Fugenlaut (in German)](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fugenlaut) for more information

Comment: oder Schadenfreiheitsklasse

Comment: As described further in the Wikipedia article linked to above, there are also several other joining elements beside _-s-_.

Comment: "Note that the use of Fugen-s's differs in different German speaking Countries." - exactly. Here in Austria, it's always "Schadenersatz", never "Schaden**s**ersatz"

Comment: I am a German native and I've never heard or use "Schaden**s**ersatz" either. Only "Schadenersatz".

Comment: Shortly before you discussed this this blog post was published: http://www.klartext-jura.de/2014/11/02/schadensersatz-oder-schadenersatz/ Even the laws regulating *Schadensersatz* (which I would have used intuitively, I think) are not consistent.