# Is it "Vierergruppe" or "Viergruppe", or is there a distinction?

Tags: word-usage, difference, compound

I have come to accept that I will never fully understand the [formation of compound nouns in German](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/5253/fugenkonsonanten-bei-zusammengesetzten-w%C3%B6rtern).  But I would like some information about one particular example.

[Die Kleinsche Vierergruppe](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleinsche_Vierergruppe) is an important structure in the mathematical area of group theory.  The name is a compound of "Vier" and "Gruppe", and the extra "er" is something I just have to accept.  However, there are [some](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fano-Ebene) [sources](https://web.archive.org/web/20180405022423/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/67279.html) that write "Viergruppe".  So I wonder if perhaps both forms are used, but one is more common.  But then I see [this page](https://web.archive.org/web/20171002053302/http://oberbecks.de:80/volleyball/2016/05/jugendteam-schultzschulz-zweite-der-letzten-woche-siegen-bei-basic/), which, in a non-mathematical context, uses both forms in the space of four words.

What is going on?

Comment: I took the liberty to fix the typo in wikipedia. Just in case someone is wonderng what's up in the first link

Comment: The mathematical term definitely is _Kleinsche Vierergruppe_.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

For me, "*Viergruppe*" sounds simply wrong, so I consider it a typo in the sources, you found.

As mentioned in the linked answer compositions of nouns in German may have a "Fugenlaut". For combinations of numbers and other nouns this is indeed the Fugenlaut "**-er-**", e. g.

- Drei**er**gruppe
- Vier**er**gruppe
- Fünf**er**gruppe

and so on.

Comment: Worth noting that the math text is in English and we can safely assume that "Viergruppe" is an invalid literal translation of "four group". The German text says "die *andere* Vier**er**gruppe" referring to the "Viergruppe" mentioned before. "Andere" indicates that the intention was to use the same word, so that is a simple typo indeed.

Comment: It is definitely "Vier**er**gruppe" in the original: [Vorlesungen über das Ikosaeder und die Auflösung der Gleichungen vom fünften Grade](https://archive.org/details/vorlesungenber00kleiuoft/page/12)

Comment: Given that it's also "Zwei-Tupel", "Drei-Tupel" etc., I wouldn't find "Vier-Gruppe" *totally* off.

Answer (score 7):

First of all, note that compounds without *-er* (*Einauge, Zweirad, Dreisatz, Dreiklang, Dreispitz, Vierauge, Fünfkampf*) are more frequent than those with *-er*. I therefore assume compounds with *-er* have a narrower meaning.

This is borne out by the following observation. There are two ways to form number nouns: By way of zero derivation (feminine, *die Eins, Zwei, Drei*, etc.) or by adding *-er* (masculine, *der Ein(s)er, Zweier, Dreier*, etc.). The latter are more restricted than the former: They are mostly used to refer to grades (*ein Fünfer/eine Fünf in Mathe*) and money (*Ich hab nur noch 'n Fünfer*, *einen Fünfeuroschein*).

The pattern I can discern is that in compounds with *-er*, the number seems to refer to the internal structure of the object denoted by the head noun.

> Zweierzimmer *Zimmer mit zwei Betten* (Swiss German)
>   Dreierbeziehung *Beziehung zwischen drei Personen*
>   Viererabteil *Abteil für vier Personen*
>   Viererpakt *Pakt zwischen vier Parteien*

Note that these compounds can sometimes be unpacked by adding a noun for the number to count. Then *-er* vanishes.

> Zweibettzimmer, Vierpersonenabteil, Viermächtepakt

The examples you found look like mistakes to me; it should be *Vierergruppe* in all instances; this is the term [Klein used](https://archive.org/details/vorlesungenber00kleiuoft/page/12). However, there seem to be some rare (!) cases of missing *-er* that look genuine. [This dissertation](https://archive.org/details/experimentalunt00koffgoog/page/n46) from 1908 has *Eins-, Zwei-, Drei-, Viergruppe*. This could be related to the *-er* seen as a *Fugenlaut* and being stigmatized (there once was an attempt to change *verfassungsgebend* in the German constitution to *verfassunggebend*).

<sub>Having read the other answers to this question, I see that it is highly unclear what kind of *-er* this is: a nominal suffix, a genitive suffix or a *Fugenlaut*.</sub>

Comment: Also, in my experience with (older) maths books specifically, there do seem to be some weird nomenclatures around. I can't think of another example right now, but I would not be surprised if some mathematical book used "Viergruppe" consistently (although I would use "Vierergruppe" myself). Finally, what do you make of "Vierkant", "Viereck"... ;)

Comment: A *Viereck* has four corners, so the lack of *-er* isn't surprising. An interesting case could be *Zwei(er)gespann*, where the meaning would fit *-er* but the form without it occurs more frequently.

Comment: Wiktionary [notes](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Zweier) that the noun *Zweier* (or *Fünfer*) referring to a grade is Austrian or perhaps Süddeutsch.  Would you agree?

Comment: I grew up in Southern Germany and find *Fünfer* unremarkable. Now we need a Northerner's opinion :)

Comment: @gerrit Yes. That's the way pupils call the grades in colloquial speech, at least in Southern Germany.

Comment: @DavidVogt in the North, the grades are referenced as "Eins, Zwei, Drei,..", the Southern variant is extremely uncommon. Regarding the "Zweierzimmer": I once had an annoying experience with an Austrian innkeeper, who referred to his room number 6 as "das Sechserzimmer" on the phone, which I interpreted as "Sechsbettzimmer" (as would be the usual description). There were only 2 beds of course.

Comment: @Chieron That's beautiful!

Comment: It almost seems like this is an evolving, living, dynamic language. :-)

Comment: @Chieron As a Vienna native, saying "Sechserzimmer" for room number 6 would confuse me too. Seems unusual to me; it sounds extremely rural.

Comment: @SebastianRedl the Northern Waldviertel should be rural enough. It did also confuse my Viennese companions.

Answer (score 5):

Zweier, dreier, vierer ... are the genitive case of zwei, drei, vier... A "Vierergruppe" is a group of four. They can be used alone in phrases like "Streit zweier Parteien".

Comment: "Zweier, dreier, vierer ... are the genitive case of zwei, drei, vier... " doesn't sound right to me. These are just straight nominatives as far as I can tell. "Der 3er BMW" has nothing to do with a Genetiv, it's just the masculine form of "3". Genetive would be "Des Dreiers" / "Des Vierers".

Comment: @AnoE. "Zweier" in "Streit zweier Parteien" is not nominative.

Comment: It's the Genitiv Plural case, isn't it ([Wiktionary Flexion:zwei](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Flexion:zwei))?  Which begs the question: why the plural?

Comment: @gerrit. Numbers greater than one are plural by definition.

Comment: Looks like I misread the wiktionary entry.  But there is also [the noun *Zwei*](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Zwei) (plural *Zweien*?) vs. the numeral *zwei*?  But the noun has Genitiv *Zwei* and Genitiv Plural *Zweien*...

Comment: @fdb, exactly, "zweier" is not nominative. But there is a nominative "Zweier" (different word...). You can buy a "Zweier BMW" which just means "the BMW which is labeled with the 2", not "a BMW which is shared between two people". You can pay with a "Zweier" (a coing with the "2 €" on it). I'd say "Vierergruppe" is then made from the Nominative/Substantive "Vierer", not a genetive of "Vier".