# Bildung von Adjektiven aus Eigennamen

Tags: adjective, compound-adjective

In der Stochastik gibt es Adjektive, die aus Eigennamen zusammengesetzt werden. Z.b. "bernoulliverteilt". Das ist eine bestimmte Eigenschaft einer Zufallsvariable und Bernoulli der Eigenname. Mir ist nun nicht klar, welche Schreibweise richtig ist:

1. bernoulliverteilt
2. Bernoulliverteilt
3. Bernoulli-verteilt

Was sind die Regeln für die Bildung solcher Adjektive? Oder muss das ganz anders gebildet werden?

(Ich spreche Deutsch als Muttersprache)

Comment: Beispiel aus unserem Forum: https://german.stackexchange.com/q/50079/34192 . Vgl. auch https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleinsche_Vierergruppe .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hier dürfte die Regel §51 der Rechtschreibregeln des Rechtschreibrates "ziehen":

> Man kann einen Bindestrich in Zusammensetzungen setzen, die als ersten Bestandteil einen Eigennamen haben, der besonders hervorgehoben werden soll, oder wenn der zweite Bestandteil bereits eine Zusammensetzung ist.

Hier wird als Beispiel die Zusammensetzung "Richelieu-freundlich" genannt, die in der Bildung deinem Adjektiv entspricht. Damit wäre *Bernoulli-verteilt* auf jeden Fall korrekt.

Da das eine "kann"-Regelung ist, impliziert das, dass *bernoulliverteilt* im Prinzip auch richtig sein müsste (auch wenn die Regeln diesen Fall nicht explizit zu behandeln scheinen). Da das aber ein bißchen unübersichtlich aussieht, würde ich die Schreibung mit Bindestrich wahrscheinlich bevorzugen.

(2) kann in keinem Fall richtig sein, da man Adjektive klein schreibt.

Comment: "(2) kann in keinem Fall richtig sein, da man Adjektive klein schreibt." Das stimmt in dieser pauschalen Form nicht, wenn es sich wie hier um fachsprachliche Begriffe handelt.  Vgl. die Antworten zu https://german.stackexchange.com/q/31430/34192.

Comment: @PaulFrost u.a. meine Antwort da  - Ich wiederhole nochmal, was ich da geschrieben habe: Die *Regel* sagt, man soll Adjektive klein schreiben und bemerkt: Manche schreiben sie trotzdem groß.