# How to determine which connector to use in compound word?

Tags: compound

How do you determine which connector (if any) to use when building compound words?

For example, is `history homework`:

> Geschichtehausaufgaben
>   Geschichtenhausaufgaben
>   Geschichteenhausaufgaben
>   Geschichtshausaufgaben
>   Geschichteshausaufgaben
>   Geschichteehausaufgaben

How can you determine which one to use, especially in words which you would probably not be able to find on the internet due to their obscurity (i.e two nouns that don't usually go together)?

Comment: Related: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/5253/fugenkonsonanten-bei-zusammengesetzten-w%c3%b6rtern/5271#5271

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't agree with Janka's answer. You can't just pick any *Fugenlaut* that sounds good to you. In most cases there is only one correct version. In the case of *Geschichte* and *Hausaufgaben* it is true that there are two possibilities:

> Geschichtehausaufgaben

and

> Geschichtshausaufgaben

as mentioned by Janka. I have heard both. Personally, I prefer the latter. Also when you google *Geschichtehausaufgaben* it asks: "Did you mean Geschichtshausaufgaben."

But as I said, in most cases there is one possibility only. *Haus* (house) and *Tür* (door) can only be connected as *Haustür* (front door) although *Hausetür* or *Hausentür*  are easy to pronounce as well. *Steichenholz* would even be easier to say than the correct form *Streichholz* (match) (the one to make fire) (compound of streichen - to strike and Holz - wood). But only the latter is correct.

Unfortunately, I'm not firm enough in grammar to tell you what rules apply or if there are any at all. But I am pretty sure that it is determined by the first word. If I think about a word, I have a clear preference how to connect it with another word even if I haven't thought about a second word or when the resulting word would be complete nonsense. E.g. if I want to build a word with *Tisch* (table) in front, I already know that I will use the *Nullfuge* no matter what the second word will be.

On the German Wikipedia page to *Fugenlaut* it is stated that two studies have shown that the *Nullfuge* is used in over 70% of all examined words. So if you're not sure what to use, the *Nullfuge* should be a good guess.

Comment: As I had put it: *As a non-native speaker, you have to make a lucky guess.*

Answer (score 3):

It's either

> Geschichtehausaufgaben *(Nullfuge)*

or, also common

> Geschicht**s**hausaufgaben *(s-Fuge)*

The only other option from your list which isn't a tongue-twister is

> Geschichte**n**hausaufgaben *(n-Fuge)*

But *Geschichten* are *stories*, not *history*, so you cannot use that variant.

Dialects may even use

> Geschichtlhausaufgaben

for story writing homework.

---

How do you select the correct *Fugenlaut*? There isn't correct and incorrect here, just variants that are hard to pronounce (especially the Nullfuge may be hard to pronounce) and variants that create ambiguity. And variants that are common in your dialect and those which aren't.

As a non-native speaker, you have to make a lucky guess.

Comment: So you can use whichever one you like, so long as it doesn't have an alternate meaning and sounds normal?

Comment: Yes. As long you can pronounce it easily. German has enough tongue-twisters already.